# UNET dedicated server. How can i make it resource wise?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, dedicated-server, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

My goal is to use UNET dedicated server for production, but over 100 MB of RAM per session(3-6 players) is obviosuly too much. How can I force server to not load models/audio/textures?

Answer (score 0):

Run your build in batchmode ?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

"**-batchmode** :   Run the game in “headless” mode. The game will not display anything or accept user input. This is mostly useful for running servers for networked games."